# Module not found when new dependency is installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am working on a AWS Lambda using NodeJs. On an existing repository, I added `axios` as dependency.

When importing `axios`, I encountered `Module not found` but when importing old dependency (tested it by importing `aws-sdk`), it doesn't encounter the issue.

I previously encountered the same issue when I was working on a different project (still AWS Lambda) but I encounter it when importing `speakeasy`.

Checking the `node_modules` directory, the `axios` directory exists.

NOTE:
 - Encountered same issue with yarn and npm
 - Tried adding `lodash` and I didn't encounter the issue.
 - Visual Studio Code and WebStorm detects axios
 - `node-fetch` encounters the same issue.

Comment: Does this problem persist after reinstalling the axios module?

Comment: Yes, same issue.

Comment: How did you get your codes into aws-lambda? Have you used Cloud 9 or aws-sam-cli?

Comment: I am using aws-sam-cli.

Comment: Have you checked the node_modules of the inline code of aws-lambda?

Comment: I've check the node_modules, `axios` is in the `node_modules` directory.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191396/aws-lambda-issue

Comment: It requirs 20 reputation points. :(

Comment: Just by adding `require('axios')`, I already encounter the issue

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue on this. It is on the location of the `node modules`.

So what my current folder structure is (Which encounter the problem)

```
my_project
-- app
   -- handler.js
-- package.json
-- node_modules
```

With the structure above, the actual error is that `XMLHttpRequest` is undefined which `axios` or other `http` library uses.

**What I did is move the package.json to the `app` directory**

```
my_project
-- app
   -- handler.js
   -- package.json
   -- node_modules
```

**NOTE**

- This is used in AWS APIGateway and Lambda not running in a NodeJS server locally.

Comment: The before and after of your folder structure is the exact same